# Can sinatra listen to more than one port?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want one running **sinatra** application to **listen on two ports** 80 and 4567?

Is that possible

- on Windows XP
- using ruby only
- running only one instance of my sinatra application?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case for this?

Comment: I developed the whole application while using the standard 4567 port. It was just a tool for myself but now I will 'release' it for others too so I thought it would be 'better' use standard port 80. Then I thought it would be nice if I can have it running on both ports. Looks like I will go for 80 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. It's called port forwarding. You run your app on port 80 and forward port 4567 to 80. That way you can have both ports. Or you do it the other way round where you run your local app and forward the protected port 80 to your 4567 port. That's btw how most hosting services run their client's apps.

Comment: yes, iptables does it on *nixes. It looks difficult, it isn't difficult but still...

Comment: Can I do so on Windows? Can I use `ruby solution` only?

Comment: @Radek - Google found [this utility](http://www.quantumg.net/portforward.php). I don't see any Ruby methods for controlling the Windows settings on Windows (though if you can find a command line solution of course you can call out to that using Ruby backticks).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, no it's not - https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb

Answer (score 2):

You could launch two different copies of the application, sharing the same database:

```
ruby myapp.rb -p 80 &
ruby myapp.rb -p 4567 &
```

These would run in two separate Ruby processes, which may or may not cause a problem (depending on if you are storing any information in the process). However, the default cookie-based sessions even work across processes:

```ruby
require 'sinatra'

enable :sessions
get '/in/:msg' do
  session[:msg] = params[:msg]
  "I stored #{session[:msg]}"
end

get '/out' do
  "Here you go: #{session[:msg]}"
end
```

In action:

```
phrogz$ ruby sessions.rb -p 3000 &
[1] 58698

phrogz$ ruby sessions.rb -p 3001 &
[1] 58699

phrogz$ curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt http://localhost:3000/in/foo
I stored foo

phrogz$ curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt http://localhost:3000/out
Here you go: foo

phrogz$ curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt http://localhost:3001/out
Here you go: foo
```

Comment: I don't use db. Only rb code. Can I share variables across two instances of the same application? If I want to be sure that something is executed only once at a time I need to know somehow that it's being running...

Comment: @Radek I don't fully understand your requirements.

Comment: I use my sinatra application to run test automation scripts that can take long time to finish. I need to make sure that if one instance of sinatra starts the testing another testing script will not be started again. Can I use without storing such info outside of sinatra? Just in memory?

Comment: Personally, I would use a separate DRb process for that that. I would never let my Sinatra process lock up while it's running a test - thus you need to kick off another thread and use a mutex to watch the state. It's super easy to use DRb as another process on the machine that looks like a native Ruby object, supporting all your existing methods and calls.

Comment: The thing is that I understood nothing you said ... I know now it can be done somehow. I use only one sinatra rb file. Could you point me to some tutorial for newbies where I can learn how to do what you suggested?

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using puma to start the application, then you can do something like:

```
bundle exec puma -b tcp://0.0.0.0:3000 -b tcp://0.0.0.0:4000
```